# How can I reso;ve the error "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ',0)"

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
protected void dgMenuSubItems_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!(e.CommandName == "AddANewRow"))
            return;

        string str1 = this.dgMenuItems.DataKeys[this.dgMenuItems.SelectedIndex].ToString();

        TextBox textBox1 = e.Item.FindControl("txtSubItemNameF") as TextBox;
        TextBox textBox2 = e.Item.FindControl("txtSubItemPriceF") as TextBox;
        TextBox textBox3 = e.Item.FindControl("txtSubItemSortOrderF") as TextBox;

        if (textBox1 != null && textBox2 != null)
        {
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(clsADO.getSingleRecord("Select Max(SubItemId) from tbl_MenuSubItems"));
            string text1 = textBox1.Text;
            string text2 = textBox2.Text;
            string str2 = text1.Replace("''", "''");
            string str3;

            try
            {
                str3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text).ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
               str3 = "0";
            }

            clsADO.executeNonQuery("Insert into tbl_MenuSubItems values ('" + (object) (num + 1) + '",'" + str2 + "','" + text2 + "','" + str1 + "','" + str3 + "')");
        }
        else
            this.lblError.Text = "Error finding the SubItem";

        this.Rebuild_Sub_Display();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.lblError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Here I am inserting values into database, but I'm getting error:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ',0)'. Incorrect syntax near ',0)'

I think I am missing a quotation mark, but I don't have any idea where exactly I am missing it

Comment: You should use parameters. This way if user has put ' in text, then this will fail and second for SQL Injection.

Comment: Please use SqlCommand instead of plain text when executing your sql query. Also like @NikhilAgrawal said you should add parameters correctly. See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info

Comment: Shouldn't this `string str2 = text1.Replace("''", "''");` be `string str2 = text1.Replace("'", "''");`

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because that's an **awful** way to account for single quotes going into sql.

Comment: Also, we need to see a lot more about clsADO to know how to help you. You'll probably need to update it to support good query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you should use sqlcommand and sqlparameters to do that all. anyway
  your insert query must be like this ,you have made incorrect string

```
Insert into tbl_MenuSubItems values ('" + (object) (num + 1) + "','" + str2 + "','" + text2 + "','" + str1 + "','" + str3 + "')
```

your non query line must be

```
clsADO.executeNonQuery("Insert into tbl_MenuSubItems values ('" + (object) (num + 1) + "','" + str2 + "','" + text2 + "','" + str1 + "','" + str3 + "')");
```